# vue-test-utils throws an error 'TypeError: inject is not a function'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I wrote a global plugin and used it in a component.

plugins/passwordValidation.js:

```js
export default function ({ app }, inject) {
  inject('passwordValidation', (password, passwordForConfirming) => {
    const errors = []
    ...
    return errors
  })
}
```

```js
...
<script>
...
export default { 
  ...
  watch: {
    password(newPassword, oldPassword) {
      this.passwordValidationWarnings = this.$passwordValidation(
        newPassword,
        this.passwordForConfirming
      )
    },
  ...
}
</script>
```

Then after writing a test with reference to [the documentation](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#applying-global-plugins-and-mixins), I noticed an following error occurred.

An error message:

```
 FAIL  test/components/organisms/RegisterForm.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: inject is not a function

      1 | export default function ({ app }, inject) {
    > 2 |   inject('passwordValidation', (password, passwordForConfirming) => {
        |   ^
      3 |     const errors = []
```

test/components/organisms/RegisterForm.spec.js:

```js
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex, { Store } from 'vuex'
import RegisterForm from '@/components/organisms/RegisterForm.vue'
import passwordValidation from '@/plugins/passwordValidation.js'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.use(passwordValidation)

describe('RegisterForm', () => {
  describe('When the registration succeeds', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      ...
      wrapper = shallowMount(RegisterForm, {
        localVue,
        ...
      })
    ...
    })
```

How can I fix this error to use the plugin in my test?

For reference, the versions of the applications used are as follows.

- nuxt: 2.15.8
- @vue/test-utils: 1.3.0
- jest: 27.5.1

Comment: It's likely Nuxt plugin, while you use it as Vue plugin, so second argument (inject) is not provided. This is only the tip of the iceberg, you'll constantly have problems when using test utility that is unaware of nuxt with nuxt app. You may want to check https://test-utils.nuxtjs.org/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll install nuxt/test-utils and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I give up using `@nuxt/test-utils` as it doesn't have the necessary features such as mocking and stubbing. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It still uses Jest. It's Jest's responsibility to provide mocking

Comment: Oh really? I thought so because `@nuxt/test-utils` doesn't have `shallowMount`. So is there a way to mock Vuex and stub custom components using Jest?

Comment: By using jest.mock. It may be less convenient for unique mocks per test but otherwise that's it, you can mock any module, this isn't specific to Vue